# LEFT JOIN Not working properly in connecting two tables

Tags: sql

Here i am doing cab allocation module,here i will explain my requirement,admin allocate the cab to the employees in shift wise.this details i stored in cab_allocation allocation table.

> cab_allocation (Table Name)

```
allocationId                date                  cabId    shiftTiming

1                         2017-08-12              CBX100     1
2                         2017-08-12              CBX100     2
3                         2017-08-12              CBX101     3
```

Here **cabId** CBX100 having two allocation and CBX101 having one allocation per day. after this i want to track this trip is happening or not, for this tracking details i stored in trip_details table

> trip_details (table name)

```
tripId    cabNo    shiftId   tripDate   startTime   endTime    tripStatus

 1       CBX100      1       2017-08-12  09:30:00    11:30:00       1
 2       CBX100      2       2017-08-12  12.10.00                    0
```

Here cabId CBX100 has completed his shiftId 1, shiftId start time is 09:30:00 and end time 11:30:00  and tripStatus 1 that means this trip is completed.

Next cabId CBX100 has started second shift, start time is 12.10.00 , but this trip is not completed so there is no end time and tripstatus

Next cabId CBX101 has not started his trip, so there is no entry is this table,

Now my expected result is which are the trip is incomplete i want to take details in cab allocation. here cab_allocation table allocationId i am using forien key trip_details table tripId.

> I tried but i am not getting exact result,because CBX101 cabId not yet started his trip ,so entry not there in trip_details table, so i am not able get details.

I Tried like this

```
$sql = " SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation a LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId WHERE b.tripStatus !='1'";
  $mysql = mysql_query($sql);
  $count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
  if($count > 0){
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
  $arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
  echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }else{
    $arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
    echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }
```

> I am getting Results

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "count": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "allocationId": "2",
            "date": "2017-08-12",
            "shiftTiming": "2",
            "cabId": "CBX100",
        }
    ]
    }
```

> Expected Results

```
    {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "allocationId": "2",
            "date": "2017-08-12",
            "shiftTiming": "2",
            "cabId": "CBX100",
        },
        {
            "allocationId": "3",
            "date": "2017-08-12",
            "shiftTiming": "3",
            "cabId": "CBX101",
        },
    ]
    }
```

My Update Code

```
    $sql = " SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation a LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId WHERE b.tripId is null or b.tripStatus !='1' ";
$mysql = mysql_query($sql);
$count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
if($count > 0){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
$arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}else{
$arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}
      $data[] = $row;
      mysql_num_rows($mysql)--;
}
$arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}else{
$arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}
```

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) in new projects. It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be ware of left outer join, if you filter on the left table. You have to add an explicit condition to get the null value :

```
SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId 
    FROM cab_allocation a 
    LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId 
    WHERE b.tripId is null or b.tripStatus !='1'
```

[Here is and example of the query on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c486c/2) :

your php code will be like:

```
<?php
  $sql = " SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation a LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId WHERE b.tripId is null or b.tripStatus !='1' ";

  $mysql = mysql_query($sql);
  $count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
  if($count > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    $arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
    echo json_encode($arrayName);
  }else{
    $arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
    echo json_encode($arrayName);
  }
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code but i am not getting correct answer {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}

Comment: {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}, i am getting this, but this not actual result

Comment: Please check my database how it will,i explaining top of my code

Comment: i just copy and pasted your code but i am getting this error <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in
<b>C:\xampp5\htdocs\magicTravels\ipaddress.php</b> on line
<b>25</b>
<br />

Comment: Mr@ wargre , i don't know what i amdoing wrong please check my updated code (it is top of my code).again and again i am getting same error <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Can't use function return value in write context in <b>C:\xampp5\htdocs\magicTravels\ipaddress.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />

Comment: $data[] = $row;
      mysql_num_rows($mysql)--;
}   is duplicated in your code. Remove the 2nd occurence.

Comment: Can you please update my all code, i tried but i am not getting

Comment: @ wargre are you there, i am using your code but i facing some problem

Comment: you should not have problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add one more condition in where clause:
   WHERE b.tripStatus !='1' OR b.tripStatus == NULL

you use something like that.may be its help for you.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation a LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId WHERE b.tripStatus !='1' OR b.tripStatus == NULL";
$mysql = mysql_query($sql);
$count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
if($count > 0){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
$arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}else{
$arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}
      $data[] = $row;
      mysql_num_rows($mysql)--;
}
$arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}else{
$arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Can't use function return value in write context in <b>C:\xampp5\htdocs\magicTravels\ipaddress.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Comment: i have edited the where clause for your expected output.

Comment: {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}, i am getting this, but this not actual result

Comment: Please check my database how it will,i explaining top of my code

Answer (score 0):

Using the second table in WHERE transforms the left join into an inner join,so move it on the JOIN condition

```
SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId 
FROM cab_allocation a 
LEFT JOIN trip_details b 
ON a.allocationId = b.tripId AND b.tripStatus !='1'
```

Comment: I tried your code it is not working fine,are you there